# How do you set EditText to only accept numeric values in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in which I want only integer values to be inserted. Can somebody tell me which property I have to use?

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70189238/12272687

Comment: Mori's comment is the best answer here. Have you considered answering this question with it, @Mori?

Answer (score 422, accepted):

Add [`android:inputType="number"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) as an XML attribute.

Comment: Man, I love Android dev... such a fuss to get this option in web pages!

Comment: Hi, in android 2.3.3, it is "numberSigned". Just wrote it down here, in case someone is seeking for it :)

Comment: What if my editText appears in the dialog, and thus, I only declare it in .java code? i.e. the dialog editText does not appear in XML file. How can I still achieve this?

Comment: In addition, you could use `android:inputType="phone"` in place of that. But it seems a bit more "busy".

Answer (score 134):

For example:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myNumber"
android:digits="0123456789."
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
/>
```

Comment: This is the best solution !

Comment: I'm assuming the string should read `0123456789.` and not `0123456780.`

Comment: This works with android:inputType="number" as well!  I needed it in order to prevent users from typing operators, parentheses, etc. on the number pad.  What a life saver, man!

Welcome to Costco; I love you!

Comment: This will not allow you to put negative numbers and at same time it will allow duplicate decimals.(ex: 1.1.1.....)

Comment: Nice, adding android:digits also handles the copy-and-paste case.

Comment: Hey. I needed to allow commas between numbers. Guess what? digits="0123456789," works!

Answer (score 111):

In code, you could do

```
ed_ins.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: @MohamedKhamis it's the name of the EditText

Comment: Sourabh asked for "Only integer values to be inserted". This allows to input a lot more.

Answer (score 42):

For only digits input use `android:inputType="numberPassword"` along with `editText.setTransformationMethod(null);` to remove auto-hiding of the number.

OR

`android:inputType="phone"`

For only digits input, I feel these couple ways are better than `android:inputType="number"`. The limitation of mentioning "number" as inputType is that the keyboard allows to switch over to characters and also lets other special characters be entered. "numberPassword" inputType doesn't have those issues as the keyboard only shows digits. Even "phone" inputType works as the keyboard doesnt allow you to switch over to characters. But you can still enter couple special characters like +, /, N, etc.

**android:inputType="numberPassword"** with **editText.setTransformationMethod(null);**

[image: inputType="numberPassword"]

**inputType="phone"**

[image: inputType="phone"]

**inputType="number"**

[image: inputType="number"]

Comment: This is Perfect! `android:inputType="numberPassword"` along with `editText.setTransformationMethod(null);`

Comment: this tip makes what my application is made perfect.

Answer (score 6):

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: This is great, but the Integer number system doesn't include any decimal numbers.

Comment: @RileyE What do you mean by this? We just started using this for all our numeric inputs and I want to make sure we're not missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Question says "numeric" but question text says "integer"

Answer (score 4):

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/age"
android:numeric="integer" 
/>
```

Comment: android:numeric is deprecated since API 3, see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625380/difference-among-edittext-androidnumeric-decimal-and-androidinputtype-numbe

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
Edittext_name.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

It will allow you to enter just numbers. You cannot enter chars.
if you want to enter chars, not numbers, you can edit the values between the quotes inside `getInstance`.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone want to use only number from 0 to 9 with `imeOptions` enable then use below line in your `EditText`

> android:inputType="number|none"

This will only allow number and if you click on done/next button of keyboard your focus will move to next field.

Answer (score 2):

using the below can solve your problem better;

in xml:

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/age"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"        />
```

or //in activity inside etfield.addtextchangelistener

```
     private String blockCharacterSet="+(/)N,*;#";//declare globally
               try {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {


                    if (blockCharacterSet.contains(s.charAt(i) + "")) {

                        String corrected_settempvalue = arrivalsettemp.substring(0, arrivalsettemp.length() - 1);
                        et_ArrivalSetTemp.setText(corrected_settempvalue);
                        if (corrected_settempvalue.length() != 0)
                            et_ArrivalSetTemp.setSelection(corrected_settempvalue.length());

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception d) {
                d.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in XML

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/myNumber"
 android:digits="123"
 android:inputType="number"
/>
```

or,

```
android:inputType="numberPassword" along with editText.setTransformationMethod(null); to remove auto-hiding of the number.
```

or,

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

Programmatically you can use
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

Answer (score 0):

I need to catch pressing Enter on a keyboard with [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher). But I found out that all numeric keyboards android:inputType="number" or "numberDecimal" or "numberPassword" e.t.c. don't allow me to catch Enter when user press it.

I tried `android:digits="0123456789\n"` and all numeric keyboards started to work with Enter and TextWatcher.

So my way is:

```
android:digits="0123456789\n"
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

plus `editText.setTransformationMethod(null)`

Thanks to barmaley and abhiank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the correct answer was in '13, but today it is:

`myEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(null, false, true));  //  positive decimal numbers`

You get everything, including the onscreen keyboard is a numeric keypad.

ALMOST everything. Espresso, in its infinite wisdom, lets `typeText("...")` inexplicably bypass the filter and enter garbage...

Comment: @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)

Comment: Point. I'm on `.Q`, because our project is not mass-market

Answer (score 0):

To enforce a numeric keyboard WITH access to a decimal separator that is appropriate for the locale, you can use below code

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(locale);
String digits = decimalFormat.toLocaleString("#,###");

EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(digits));
```

the EditText will always display a numeric keyboard with access to a decimal separator that is appropriate for the locale.

Answer (score -5):

the simplest for me

```
android:numeric="integer"
```

although this also more customize

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Comment: android:numeric is deprecated since API 3, see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625380/difference-among-edittext-androidnumeric-decimal-and-androidinputtype-numbe