# Difference among EditText android:numeric="decimal" and android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Tags: android

I was wondering, what is the difference among the 2?

```
        <EditText                
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

---

```
        <EditText                
            android:numeric="decimal" />
```

I realize both gives same behavior. They limit the user input to "**0123456789.**"

So, is there any differences among the 2? Is there any preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these attributes are deprecated:

```
android:numeric
android:phoneNumber
android:inputMethod
android:capitalize
android:autoText
```

in favor of one attribute:

```
android:inputType
```

(Remember deprecated features will disappear someday in a future release, so it is always best to use the supported version.)

---

For whatever reason their deprecation is not marked in the TextView (or EditText) documentation... However they are properly annotated on the [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) page and presumably you will see the warnings inside your IDE's XML compiler (at least in Android's Eclipse plug-in.)

Comment: Thanks. But when I look through the documentation, I do not see deprecated wording : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:numeric May I know where can I get such official info?