# How can I ensure a numeric decimal keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an EditText that requires unsigned decimal input.

If I use:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
setKeyListener(NumericDigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false, true));
```

Then it works fine in the US, but my European customers can't use it because it doesn't seem to allow a comma as the decimal point.

If, on the other hand, I use:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("01234567890.,"));
```

then it works fine in the US and in Europe, but on some devices (like the Galaxy S3) the soft keyboard that comes up is strictly numeric (no comma OR period).

How can I enforce a numeric keyboard WITH access to a decimal separator that is appropriate for the locale?

Thanks

Comment: You mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android

Comment: No, I'm afraid; that's exactly my 2nd solution above, but if I do that, it doesn't work on all devices (some come up without any way to insert a decimal separator).

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using `setKeyListener()`? AFAIK, just the `setInputType()` should be sufficient.

Comment: I wanted to ensure that either decimal separator would be allowed.  In any case, if remove the setKeyListener and I set my locale to Italian, it's not letting me put in a comma, and the period that it is letting me do (correctly) being treated as a thousand's separator.  E.g., "3.14" in the Italian locale is parsed as "314".  ("3,14" would be the correct way to represent Pi.)

Comment: Here's the Android bug I'm trying to work around: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626

Comment: @EricBerman What exactly is your problem? Can't you just let the user input the number using the locale chosen, and then figure out the locale's way of separating the thousands, and parse it? I guess that's the whole point of having different locale settings...

Comment: @jadkik94, as he states, on some devices the soft keyboard comes up without the character needed. Thus it's not possible for a user to enter a decimal number at all in their locale, should they have such a device.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution / workaround is to provide [your own keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard). It should be quiete easy to implement for a calculator