# IntegerView instead of TextView

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, textview, integer

I have an Integer that I want to display in a TextView.  Instead of having Textview foo and int foo with the same number all the time, I was hoping there was a way to do something like IntegerView.  (A TextView that only takes integers) or that serves the same purpose.  Please ask if you need clarification.  My objective is to keep my code clean instead of either parsing 100 variables or having 200 variables instead of 100.

**Simplification:**

In class A, I have *int a*.  I want to display *int a* in a TextView and then send it to class B.  I want to keep my code as clean and elegant as possible.  Suggestions?

**Coding**:

```
private TextView tvFoo;
private int foo;

public void thing(){
tvFoo.setText("" + foo);
DifferentClass.someMethod(foo);
}
```

---

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvFoo" />
```

****I have a lot of variables to mess with, so I am trying to eliminate one of the 2.

Thanks!

Comment: another clarification...I know IntegerView does not exist.  But that would be what I'd want to use if it did.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why can't you just use `TextView` and set the text to be an integer value?

Comment: cuz that would require me doubling the number of variables.  I would need to have int a and also TextView a. i was hoping there was a way around it

Comment: so instead of TextView, i was hoping there was something like IntegerView to put in my xml. or something that would serve the same purpose. maybe this is just a pipedream tho :) i want my textview to actually hold an Integer instead of changing it to a String and then back again

Comment: If I get it right, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android

Comment: getting closer. but then i still need to change it back from a TextView to an Integer before I send it to the other class. ill put some code up to help clarify

Comment: ok put some coding up there that should explain it better. let me know if u have any questions and thanks for helping!

Comment: have you chekced String.valueOf(int)

Comment: i appreciate all of the help, but it appears my question is confusing because im looking for an answer that does not exist.  the only solution to my problem would be IntegerView instead of TextView. ill stop being lazy and just parse the stuff. thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass TextView.

```
public class IntegerView extends TextView {
    ...
    public void setInt(int value) {
        setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }
    public int getInt() {
        return Integer.valueOf(getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Put it in your xml layouts this way:

```
<com.package.to.IntegerView android:id="@+id/intView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the NumberPicker from this library.
https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers