# Android TextWatcher afterTextChanged

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have to take the value of the EditText and divide it by 1.21....where is the error

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int end) {


        }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        double imponibile21;
        Importo.getText().toString();
        if (spinnerIva.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("21%")){

        Double value = Double.valueOf(""+Importo);
        imponibile21 = (value/1.21);

        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String Imponibile = formatter.format(imponibile21 );
        mImponibile.setText(Imponibile);
```

Error:

```
    09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText{421f9c38 VFED..CL .F...... 0,664-1080,781 #7f08000b app:id/ed_importo_fattura}"
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:114)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at fatture.acquisti.Inserisci_fatture$2.afterTextChanged(Inserisci_fatture.java:178)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7841)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9754)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:676)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:196)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-18 22:59:56.617: E/AndroidRuntime(27425):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the error you're facing with ?

Comment: I have included the error

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion from `String` to `Double` is not working correctly, hence the `java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)` error. This error is occurring at line 63 in your code (java:63).

Try this:

```
String stringValue = Importo.getText().toString();
if(!stringValue.isEmpty()) {
    Double value = Double.valueOf(stringValue);
}
```

Comment: it works, but if I write in the EditText and then delete the app crashes!
this is the error:
NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: You are going to have to do some error checking to make sure that the `String` is not empty. A simple `if` check should do the trick. It is trying to convert "" to a `Double`, which does not work.

Comment: Sorry, a check (if) how I do it in textwatcher?
an example?
thanks

Comment: See my new edit.
You may need to check for non-numeric input as well. An easy way to avoid this is to set the input property on the `EditText` view. Here is how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to parse the `EditText` to a `Double` instead of the `String` containing the value.

Try something like that:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    double imponibile21;
    String val = s.toString();
    if (spinnerIva.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("21%")){

        Double value = Double.valueOf(val);
```

Be sure that `val` contains a valid `double`.

Comment: it works, but if I write in the EditText and then delete the app crashes! this is the error: NumberFormatException: Invalid double

Comment: That is because removing the text from a `EditText` triggers `afterTextChanged()`. You could add `if(val.length() > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
String number = Importo.getText().toString();
Double value = Double.valueOf(""+ number);
```

This is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

add `implements TextWatcher` to your class .
that solved my problem. i imported `TextWatcher` but it didnt work then i tried implementing it and it works perfectly.

Comment: while this can answer the question you should try to improve it with explanation and relevant code. see [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)