# can't get integer number from EditText

Tags: android

Hello I am very new in android 
I am trying to get integer value from  an EditText, But When I am parsing string to Integer I got NumberFormatException.
Please help me to come out of this error. 
thanks in advance.

Program is:

```
int day,month,year;
    EditText expense,ammount;
    String[] exp=new String[10];
    int[] amt=new int[10];
    int count=0;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        final TextView txtdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);

        expense=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.exp);
        ammount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amnt);


        final Button add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        final Button cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
        final Button done=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btndone);



        txtdate.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {

            getval(); 
            }

        });
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                clean();



            }

        });
        done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                total();
                getval();    
                clean();

       final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       tv.setText(Integer.toString(total()));
            }

            private int total() {
                int total = 0;

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
                {

                    total+=amt[i];

                }
                return total;

            }

        });

    }
    protected void clean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        expense.setText(" ");
        ammount.setText(" ");

    }
    protected void getval() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         final Editable e2=expense.getText();
         final Editable e1=ammount.getText();

         final int i=Integer.parseInt(e1.toString());
         amt[count]=i;
         exp[count]=e2.toString();
         System.out.println(amt[count]);
         System.out.println(exp[count]);
         count++;

    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse ' 600' as integer
```

Comment: what is value of e1 `'600'` or `600`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
final int i=Integer.parseInt(e1.toString().trim());
```

bacause there is a space before that number see `' 600'` that's why that error..

Hope this will help..

Answer (score 5):

Remove any leading or trailing spaces from the number first:

```
int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString().trim());
```

Alternatively, you can remove all non-numeric characters from the string using regular expressions:

```
String cleanInput = editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(cleanInput);
```

Though if non-numeric input characters is a problem you'd probably want to restrict the EditText to numeric only. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android). It says to add the following attribute to the EditText:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in your integer.

Add the following attribute to your EditText in your xml to only allow entering integers:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
final int f = -1; // or other invalid value
if (edittext.getText().toString().length() > 0)
f = Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
```