# Check user input in Android

Tags: android

I would like to check user supplied data before adding it to a database.

The user enters the input by using standard EditText fields, which are created dynamically and grouped in an array list.

```
                EditText ExerciseEditText = this.ExerciseList.get(n); //get content from EditText at given index
                String exercise = ExerciseEditText.getText().toString();
```

I'm using the same concept for two different types of input:

- text data
- numbers

they are all of the type String and their type should be maintained.

By using those string I would like to determine which type of data the user entered and check it against some rules.

In the "number" fields the user should only be allowed to enter something like this "123", but not "asdf".

To accomplish this I have implemented a method which tries to parse the string to an int.

```
private Boolean intCheck(String intString)
{
    try 
    { 
        int parsedString = Integer.parseInt(intString);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    { 
        String error = e.toString();
        Log.w("Fail", error); //debug
        return false;
    }   

}
```

Whenever there is invalid input it will throw an exception and return false

```
EditText WeightEditText = this.WeightList.get(n);   
String weight = WeightEditText.getText().toString();    

                if (intCheck(weight) == false)
                {
                    while (intCheck(weight) == false)
                    {
                        requestNewVal("reps");
                        reps = MainActivity.NewUserInput;                           
                    }                       
                }
```

My requestNewVal() method should prompt the user for a new value(number) and assign the value to the string. Then it checks again and should keep prompting the user for new data until a valid number is entered.

```
private void requestNewVal(String string)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Error");
    alert.setMessage("Please enter "+string);

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
        {
            String newVal = input.getText().toString();
            MainActivity.NewUserInput = newVal;
        }
    });

    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.show();       
}
```

MainActivity.NewUserInput is a global variable and it's not jet initialized.

And this is were my problem lays, the program is not prompting the user at all and it just assigns a null value to the string, causing an infinite row of Exceptions.
After that the program freezes...

Will setting a OnClickListener solve the problem?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wondering, is there a reason that you have to be able to put in any value? You can set the input type in the xml layout.

Comment: Just a note that in Java it is considered best practice to make all object variable names start with a lower case letter, such as exerciseEditText instead of ExerciseEditText.

Comment: How do you shoot down my comment, and then accept an answer that suggests the same thing?

Comment: First I was thinking about the principle of never trusting the client, but then after reading your comment I started testing out some other input methods. It seems that the protection Android offers is good enough for my purpose, so I accepted your answer. Sorry for shooting down your comment, I deleted mine now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify that your EditText only allows numerical input.

**Programmatically:**

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

OR

**In Layout File:**

```
< EditText
android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
android:inputType="number" />
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android)

Comment: Nice... i will try this.