# Android EditText force numeric keyboard but allow non-numeric chars

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I need to maintain an `EditText` which can be inputted by the user numbers, at some cases I need to set the text of the `EditText` to something like 12$. So I need to be able to `setText()` to anything I want.

I've tried setting up an EditText with input type set to number which yields the numeric keypad and also remove the `InputFilter`'s of that EditText - Which still does not allow me to put non numeric chars

```
input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {});
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different way to accomplish my goal, an EditText with a numeric keypad that i can programmatically insert some non numeric chars into?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will keep it numeric but will allow the $ character, add any other special chars you need to the `android:digits` attribute

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789,$">
```

Comment: FYI: android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, " Space works as well (see space! at the end)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to aviran's answer.  If you put any "," in the string then you will also allow commas in the EditText.

Below will only allow 0-9 and $.

`<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789$">`

Answer (score 0):

Set input type Phone in xml.

This could help you...

[how to set only numeric value for edittext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android)