# How to allow only integer value in input field for mobile application

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app, meteor-blaze

I am using **meteor+blaze** for application development and need to allow only integer value in **number** input field for user details form.

I tried to use **keypress/keyup** events for input type nuber but not able to get the event for decimal point, android mobile number keypad return same **keycode 229** for **.,-** keys and when i return false for keycode 229, it's not working. But events are working fine with number value keys on mobile.

code:

```
'keyup #weight': function (event, instance) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
            console.log(this, "Integer values only");
            return false;  // stop processing
        }
    }
```

Please advise, how can I prevent the user from entering a decimal value in the input field?

Comment: **`android:inputType="number"`**

Comment: are you talking about android solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set only numeric value for edittext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

I guess `android:inputType="number"` at the xml attributes.

**OR**

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myNumber"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="number"/>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only integers you can use:

```
 <input type="text" name="n" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

Comment: I need to check the number on keyprees/keyup events for mobile application.